# Multitasking on iOS4: Does it work only on iPhones?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, multitasking

I have iOS 4.0 on an iPod Touch 2nd Gen.

There's absolutely no multitasking working. Nothing goes to the background, and double-tapping the Home Button results in just nothing. I wanted to test my app against this new feature, but it appears that it doesn't work for iPod Touch devices?

Does that only work on the iPhone? Or is there some minor upgrade like 4.0.0.1 that enabled multitasking? Or must I enable that somewhere, manually?

Really strange. I do the exact same thing like the Apple guys do in the demo videos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multitasking only works on the 3GS iPhones and up. You are out of luck with your 2nd Gen iPod Touch (its like the iPhone 3G, sort of). Sorry.

EDIT: You would need a 3rd Gen iPod Touch, just to be clear.

Comment: There are hacks to enable multitasking on lower devices... but take the advice of someone who tried it, and don't bother. the hardware really can't handle the extra load, and the entire device ends up sluggish. I want back to the single tasking iOS4... which, honestly, isn't that much different than 3.1.

Comment: Actually it's pretty different from 3.1 in that you can use all the apps with iOS4 specific features (which there will be more and more of).   There are a lot of new frameworks, beyond just the multitasking support...

Answer (score 8):

The documentation says:

> The ability to run background tasks is not supported on all iPhone OS–based devices. If a device is not running iPhone OS 4 and later, or **if the hardware is not capable of running applications in the background**, the system reverts to the previously defined behavior for handling applications.

You can test if it's supported with the following code:

```
UIDevice * device        = [ UIDevice currentDevice ];
BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;
if( [ device respondsToSelector: @selector( isMultitaskingSupported ) ] )
{
    backgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a 3rd gen iPod Touch for that to work. I've run into the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices) (see features section) multitasking is supported on 3rd gen iPods only

Answer (score 1):

Apple's official ipsw's (iphone software) have disabled multitasking for ipt2g. If you jailbreak you can enable multitasking for your device but the performance will be poor.

Answer (score 1):

Mutitasking is supported by 3 generation n 4g ... Iphones

Answer (score 0):

I believe UILocalNotifications, part of the multitasking package, are supported on the 2G iPod Touch and the iPhone 3G.